# how to change input value via url dynamically

Tags: php, html, parameter-passing

I am using this url to change value of Price in my code.

```
http://yoursite.com/mycart.php?am=20&product=Digitizing
```

I want that whenever I change the value of `am=` in the url , the `value='0'` must be changed in the code dynamically according to that.

```
<input type='hidden' name='li_1_price' value='0' />
```

Comment: What does this have to do with "url-rewriting"?

Comment: So you pass the price as a query string via GET? That is not a good idea. I can just change the URL to a price I want. Use a POST request or at least check the price at the backend with your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to intercept the value with PHP and then write the variable to the code.

```
<?php $amValueIs = $_GET["am"]; ?>
```

Then in your HTML

```
<input type='hidden' name='li_1_price' value='<?php echo $amValueIs; ?>' />
```

That's all there is to it.

EDIT as per comments:
If you want to be sure that "am" has a value so you don't kick up a warning:

```
$amValueIs = isset($_GET["am"]) ? $_GET["am"] : "0";
```

Which is a shorthand for "if it's set then use it, if not give it a 0".
I also added that "php" to the other open tag, just in case.

Comment: Just a few things if I may. 1) It's good to make sure that the GET array is set/not empty, same for the value in the input. 2) The `<?` in the value might trigger an error if they do not have short tags enabled.

Comment: Also, its good to sanitize that string, since you are effectively passing GET straight to html.